# What starts with the letter "t", is filled with "t" and ends in "t"?

Tags: riddle

What starts with the letter "t", is filled with "t" and ends in "t"?

Solve this riddle.

Comment: Well *obviously* it's a tnettenbutt.

Comment: (yes I know that's not how you spell tnetennba but I had to add more t's and take away some n's to make it work)

Comment: @immibis "It actually already is a word."

Comment: This doesn't work when written instead of spoken.

Comment: Yet another example of how simplistic and/or chestnut riddles often make rather poor puzzles; while they have an intended "right" answer, they are way too underspecified to exclude a lot of other possibilities, and end up getting (rightly) closed as Too Broad.  You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Here's hoping your next puzzle sees great success!

Comment: I haven't enough points to answer so:  **Teetotalist**.  Starts and ends with 'T', and since there's no alcohol involved (s)he might as well be filled with tea.  Also, imho '... is filled with' made it a dead giveaway.  I'd think about changing that to:  '... and only contains t'

Comment: @mcalex, you *always* have enough points to answer. It's possible that you don't have enough reputation to comment, but it happens that you do thanks to the site association bonus.

Comment: @Arun, I've attempted to rewrite your riddle, to narrow the potential answers and keep the intended answer. I've started a question relating to this on meta: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6225/4729

Comment: @JamesWebster "... posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count)".  I don't even see an answer box.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's a

> teapot
>  The word starts and ends with the letter T and is filled with the drink tea

Comment: In spanish the letter T is the same as the infusion drink.

Comment: I like this answer.  It's short and stout.

Answer (score 41):

Here's a few options:

> ```
>  a tea plant    (not only contains, but is made of it)
>  a tea closet   (the place you keep your tea leaves)
>  a tea set      (a number of objects holding said drink)
>  a tea shot     (if you like your tea hard and fast)
>  a tea joint    (someone will want to smoke it...)
>                 (or, a place where you drink it)
>  a tea addict   (has veins full of it)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. This is a really fascinating and funny answer, especially with the tea-addict part.

Comment: I think your last thought was wrong.

Comment: How is the last one *filled* with t?

Comment: @jpmc26, ok, that was a bit too far-fetched, sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was just kind of confused. =)

Answer (score 20):

It's a turbot fillet.

It starts with a T.

Fillet is 'filled',with a T.

It ends with a T.

Comment: That reminds me of a good old one, told to me years ago by a Scottish friend: Can you name 3 fish beginning and ending with K?  Warning 1: take some time to think about it.  Warning 2: it’s a bit of a trick question.  OK, are you ready?  Well, they are: Killer shark.  King-sized breaded haddock.  And Kilmarnock, which is a plaice in Scotland.

Answer (score 17):

T.

It starts with the letter T.

There was no specification to it being a word or just the letter.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I think James Webster's answer is the intended solution, but this is a good lateral thinking answer (and an example of why the riddle is possibly too broad).

Answer (score 12):

> [Tommy Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Bolt)

> His name starts and ends with a T, and he was a professional golfer so his all life was filled up with the [tees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee). Who knows, he might even have been fed up with the tees...

Answer (score 11):

It's

> TeaPot

Explanation follows

> Teapot starts with t and ends with t. It contains tea (t)

Comment: 4 seconds too late :P

Comment: I like how 4 seconds too late loses 43 upvotes haha

Comment: The question was posted at 08:49:16, and it took you **one and a half minutes** to answer it!? Where have you been? Sleeping? C'mon, at least try to *pretend* some committment to this site! (Kidding. One up for you, but not for James :-P)

Comment: I answered it the very moment I finished reading the question. Still, I lose the race. :(

Comment: @AeJey you got fancy with your double spoiler block and lost your window. Next time, answer first, edit in the explanation later :P

Answer (score 3):

It is

> [The Boston Tea Act](https://www.bostonteapartyship.com/tea-act)

The introduction:

> An act to allow a drawback of the duties of customs on the exportation of tea to any of his Majesty’s colonies or plantations in America; to increase the deposit on bohea tea to be sold at the India Company’s sales; and to empower the commissioners of the treasury to grant licenses to the East India Company to export tea duty-free.

The beginning of the contents:

> WHEREAS by an act, made in the twelfth year of his present Majesty’s reign, (entitled, An act for granting a drawback of part of the customs upon the exportation of tea to Ireland, and the British dominions in America...

It starts with a *T*, ends with a *t*, and has 41 instances of the word root *tea* in it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

It's a

> typist. I don't know about y'all but a typist starts and ends with T. And he can sure be filled with "T" (typing his way through life)

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly:

> An array of characters of length at least 1, with each member being the character 't'.

Answer (score 0):

> Toilet.
> Filled with tee tee.  Not vulgar, just factual.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Even if you're not trying to be vulgar, could you please edit your answer to include spoiler tags? It avoids spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at solving the puzzle themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is

> [t]ransmission line

because

> it is filled with support pillars that look like "T" [some image found on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gguK8.jpg)

and

> it is [t]erminated, usually by a [t]ransformer (or if we would like to be strict, we should say that it ends in a socke[t] or bol[t])

Answer (score -2):

OK let's start it here

> Transformationalist
>
>   Transcendentalist
>
>   Transcriptionist
>
>   Traditionalist
>
>   Territorialist
>
>   Thaumaturgist
>
>   Thanatologist
>
>   Thankfullest
>
>   Teratologist
>
>   Teetotalist
>
>   Tetravalent
>
>   Tripart
>
>   Tartlet
>
>   Tartest
>
>   Titlist
>
>   Titrant
>
>   Titbit

Comment: The question specifically asks for "filled with t", not "contain a t". Also, in the future, please use spoiler tags so that others may enjoy the puzzle as well.